# Android BluetoothLe keeping Gatt client-server connection alive

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am developing an android BLE application and I have successfully created the app which connects with the BLE peripheral. Right now Gatt server gets disconnected and reconnected again on interval of 30sec, I assume.

What I need is now to keep the connection alive in order to stream data into my data from peripheral. Why do I need that? Because it is an EMG sensor which a user would wear on the arm and plot real time data of muscle movement. I know that would reduce the battery life of the peripheral of EMG device but that doesn't matter in my case.

Does anyone have any suggestion to do that? Or Am I unaware of something which BLE offers?

I have modified this sample code for my peripheral https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Comment: Seems like a transaction is not completed correctly and therfore some side disconnects. Which side disconnects? What is the status parameter in the connection state change callback?

Comment: @Emil I get "BluetoothLe: Disconnected from GATT server." Can you suggest or  provide a sample code or something? Any hint? I am so desperate to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you should implementation [onDescriptorWriteRequest] in [BluetoothGattServerCallback.]
and then, it will maintaining connection each others.

like this:

```
override fun onDescriptorWriteRequest(device: BluetoothDevice?, requestId: Int, descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor?, preparedWrite: Boolean, responseNeeded: Boolean, offset: Int, value: ByteArray?) {
        super.onDescriptorWriteRequest(device, requestId, descriptor, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value)
        consoleOut("onDescriptorWriteRequest");

        server?.sendResponse(device , requestId , BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS , 0 , value);
    }
```